# How can I change the menu content after user log in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a menu bar defined in the "HomeController" with a login button.

My login form is a ui-bootstrap modal whose controller is "LoginController".

After successfully log in, user is directed to another state. But I also want the "Login" button to hide and show the current user's email.

I think I should use either localstorage or cookies to store the current user information. the localstorage data never expires so I think cookies is better?

So what should I do in my "LoginController" and "MainController"?
Can I use the $emit and $on?

I'm new to angular.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-home.html',
        controller:'mainController'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        parent:'home',
        onEnter:['$stateParams','$state','$modal','$resource',function($stateParams,$state, $modal, $resource){
            $modal.open({
                animation: true,
                size:'',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
                controller:'loginController'
            }).result.then(function(){
                console.log('promise resolved success');
                $state.go('admin-dashboard',{});
            },function(){
                console.log('promise rejected fail');
            }).finally(function(){
                console.log('promise finally');
                //$state.go('home',{});
            });
        }]                        
    })
    .controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$timeout,AuthToken,$window){

$scope.badCreds = false;
$scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.$dismiss();
};
$scope.login = function() {
    console.log($scope.credential);
    $http.post('/authenticate',$scope.credential).then(function success(response){
        console.log(response.data.token);
        AuthToken.setToken(response.data.token);
        $scope.currentuser = response.data.user;
        $scope.alreadyLoggedIn = true;
        console.log('success', 'Hey there!', 'Welcome ' + $scope.currentuser.email + '!');            
        $scope.$close();          
    },function error(response){
        $scope.message='Problem logging in! Sorry!';          
    });
};

$scope.logout = function(){
    AuthToken.clearToken();
    $scope.currentuser = null;
    //showAlert('info','Goodbye!','Have a great day!');
};  

<body ng-controller="mainController">
<header>        
    <div class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Westlake Pioneers</a>                  
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="team" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="blogs" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Blogs</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="projects" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a ui-sref="contact" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a ng-hide="$rootScope.currentuser" ui-sref="login" ui-sref-active="active"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></i>Login</a></li>
                    <li>{{currentuser.email}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="main">
    <div class="page {{pageClass}}" ui-view>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter into a view when using ui-router do the following:

1. Add "params" field in your 'home' route definition with an object that will hold the user name ([$stateProvider API](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)):

```js
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'template/partial-home.html',
        controller:'mainController',
        params : { userName: null }
    })
```

2. When closing modal, pass the user name of logged in user back to source (add $uibModalInstance as dependency to login controller, what's $scope.$close()?):

```js
$uibModalInstance.close(response.data.user);
```

3. Accept the username in your modal declaration:

```js
.result.then(function (loggedInUserName)
```

4. Call [$state.go](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) and pass the username to the view:

```js
$state.go('admin-dashboard',{userName:loggedInUserName});
```

5. Finally inject $stateParams to the controller that handles 'admin-dashboard' view and access it using $stateParams.userName

Alternatively, if you would like to make username available to the whole application, you can just store it in the $rootScope(dirty) or make an  [angular service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) (better).

Good luck!